# Getting error in SQL while trying to delete records with JDBC

Tags: sql, jdbc, mariadb

I am trying to write a program that deletes all data from the database (MariaDB) using JDBC but I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
    at com.iffi.AccountData.clearDatabase(AccountData.java:35)
    at com.iffi.AccountData.main(AccountData.java:679)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1098)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1371)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1031)
    at com.iffi.AccountData.clearDatabase(AccountData.java:32)
    ... 1 more
```

Here's my code:

```java
public class AccountData {

    /**
     * Removes all records from all tables in the database.
     */
    public static void clearDatabase() {
        Connection conn = ConnectionPool.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        
        List<String> tables = Arrays.asList("table1", "table2", "table3", "table4", "table5", "table6", "table7", "table8");
        
        for (String table: tables) {
            String query = "Delete from" + table + ";";
            
            try {
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                ConnectionPool.LOG.error("SQL Exception: ", e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        try {
            ps.close();
            ConnectionPool.putConnection(conn);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ConnectionPool.LOG.error("SQL Exception: ", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: There is a missing space between the from and the quotation mark. The line String query ... currently generates following content "Delete fromtable1" and so on. Which throws an sql error when trying to execute

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a space after from in your query string

Comment: That works thanks!